# What event does this trigger and how do I cancel it?

Tags: events, minecraft, bukkit

[image]

How do I prevent players from using this recipe menu? What event is called when I click the diamond?

Comment: i dont know whether you can cancel the event but maybe this is the event you are looking for: [PrepareItemCraftEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/inventory/PrepareItemCraftEvent.html)

Answer (score 1):

Currently (using minecraft 1.14 or below) you are not able to cancel the click in the recipe book. What you can do, is cancel the corresponding PlayerRecipeDiscoverEvent, to prevent the player from discovering the recipe.

There is also a permission called `minecraft.autocraft`, which "Allows the user to use the autocraft feature of the recipe book." - see https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/CraftBukkit_Commands
Using the negative permission (`-minecraft.autocraft`), will cause the autocraft feature to be blocked for the player, having the negative permission. But I think this is not what you are looking for.